# TypeError: "'TrieNode' object is not callable" - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, trie

I wrote this code to test prefix tree, but for some reason I get the error "TrieNode" object is not callable. Could someone help me resolve this error?

Why is the TrieNode() class not callable?

```
# Prefix Tree or Trie Data Structure
class TrieNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.endOfWord = False

class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

def insert(self,word):
    node = self.root()
    for w in word:
        if w not in node.children:
            node.children[w] = TrieNode()
        node = node.children[w]
    node.endOfWord = True

def search(self,word):
    node = self.root
    for w in word:
        if w not in node.children:
            return False
        node = node.children[w]

    return node.endWord

def startsWith(self,prefix):
    node = self.root
    for w in prefix:
        if w not in node.children:
            return False
        node = node.children[w]
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trie = Trie()
    trie.insert("apple")
    trie.insert("apples")
    trie.insert("bat")
    trie.insert("bate")    
    print trie.search("apple")
```

Comment: Post the full error, including the *stack trace*

Comment: `node = self.root()` is your error.  `self.root` is already a TrieNode instance and you're trying to call that.

Comment: I'm guessing from here: `node = self.root()`, but *why* would you thing that TrieNode instances are callable?

Comment: Check indentation before posting python code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read

```
def insert(self,word):
    node = self.root
```

Watch the `root()` -> `root` there. You are currently calling an instance attribute while in fact you only want to get a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks @user272298, fixed it. It was a typo on my side and I did not meant to assign root()